# Are visualStudioOnline ServiceHooks available for on-premise TFS instances?

Tags: tfs

I would like to subscribe events from our on-premise TFS instance.

But when querying for the available publishers, I get a "ServiceHooksFeatureFlagNotEnabled" exception..

```
// http://tfs/DefaultCollection/_apis/hooks/publishers?api-version=1.0

{

  "$id": "1",
  "innerException": null,
  "message": "Error in the application.",
  "typeName": "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.ServiceHooks.Publishers.Server.ServiceHooksPublisherControllerBase+ServiceHooksFeatureFlagNotEnabledException, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.ServiceHooks.Publishers.Server, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a",
  "typeKey": "ServiceHooksFeatureFlagNotEnabledException",
  "errorCode": 0,
  "eventId": 4501
}
```

Is this an imposed limitation for on-premise instances? Or this is an optional feature, that must be expressely enabled?

Our server ships a TFS2013.4.

Comment: found an answer -- it's in the Brian Harry's post
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2014/05/12/a-new-api-for-visual-studio-online.aspx
The one dated '25 Nov 2014 4:14 AM'
=> TFS 2015

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the answer is no. [This is coming in TFS 2015 if the current plans have not changed](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2014/05/12/a-new-api-for-visual-studio-online.aspx) in the mean time.